# React rerendering list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react page that has several components on it with a state that shows a modal. I dont want all the components in the app to re render when the modal shows.

```
const CustomersPage = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const dataSource = [...omitted data]

  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        visible={showModal} />

      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <Button type="primary" onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>
              Create 
            </Button>
          </div>

          <CustomForm />
        </div>

        <CustomList dataSource={dataSource} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

When the showModal value changes, the components CustomForm component and the CustomList component re renders but I dont want them to re render every time the modal shows because the list can have over 100 components. How can I do this?

Edit.

```
const CustomList = ({ dataSource }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {dataSource?.map(i => (
        <CustomCard
          id={i.id}
          ...other props
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const CustomCard = ({
  ... props
}) => {

  return (
    <>
      <Card
       ...omitted properties
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the List and Form components in a React.memo component.

This way they will only re-render when their props change their identity.

See:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/react-166-reactmemo-for-functional-components-rendering-control

Comment: I had the component wrapped in a useMemo and my superior said I dont know how to use useMemo and something else must be wrong

Comment: Could you also show the code for Form and CustomList?

Comment: I don't see any problem with wrapping those components with React.memo.
Try and use this resource to learn more about react.memo:

https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-performance

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid unnecessary re-rendering with memo and  hooks like **useMemo** and **useCallback** if you are using FC. Or if your are in CC the your create your component pure component that prevent unnecessary render.

Make your function component memo by wrapping component with Reaact.memo, then this will help to check and render component if there is any changes down there in your this child component. Despite all hooks like **useCallback**  and **useMemo** are also helpfull for optimization.

There are tons of the articles are there about the use cases of these hooks, go and have look at them. They are really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I had it wrapped in a useMemo and apparently thats not how its supposed to work

Comment: not only useMemeo, useMemo only check values, also you to check if there is any function is causing your component to retender. Also wrap child component like this if the data is not changing always. like  export default React.mem(YOUR COMPONENT NAME)